# How to optimze mysql subquery?

Tags: mysql

Need help to optimize my query, currently it runs approximately 22secs and I have 1.1 million rows in that table. Here is my query. This query is returning the users latest time in.

```
SELECT 
    t.id, t.user_id, t.created
FROM
    timesheets t
WHERE
    t.user_id IN (41649 , 41901,41899,41482,41648,41897,41652,
        41483,41900,41143,41907,16,42191,42195,42194,42136,42193,42190,42484,42485,42486,42504,
        42052,42797,42997,42868,42847,42505,42964)
    AND t.id = (SELECT 
                    MAX(sub_t.id)
                FROM
                    timesheets AS sub_t
                WHERE
                    sub_t.user_id = t.user_id
                AND sub_t.description = 'in')
```

I also have table indexes for this table (id, user_id, created, description). Any suggestion is very much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is that a single multi-column index, or do you have separate indexes on each of those columns?

Comment: Hi  @Barmar, those are sepearate indexes on each columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A multi-column index `(user_id, id)` would probably help.

Also, maybe use a join instead of correlated subquery.

```
SELECT 
    t.id, t.user_id, t.created
FROM
    timesheets t
JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(id) AS maxid
    FROM timesheets t
    WHERE user_id IN (41649 , 41901,41899,41482,41648,41897,41652,
            41483,41900,41143,41907,16,42191,42195,42194,42136,42193,42190,42484,42485,42486,42504,
            42052,42797,42997,42868,42847,42505,42964)
        AND description = "in"
    GROUP BY user_id) t1 
ON t.id = t1.maxid
```

I'm assuming `id` is the primary key of the table, so it's a unique index.

Comment: that's a huge difference, from 22sec to 0.037 sec

Comment: Was it just changing to the join, or did you also add the index?

Comment: both of your suggestion, adding multi-column index (user_id, id) makes it 6secs and then trying your query with join it took 0.037 sec. That's amazing man.